# How do I print an inverted pyramid pattern of alphabets in C?

Tags: c

I need to print this pattern:

[image]

Now, somehow I've managed to write this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    
  
    int num=64;
    int i,j,k;
    
    for(i=1;i<8;i++){
        printf("%*c", i, ' ');
        
        for(j=1;j<9-i;j++){
            printf("%c ", num+j);
            
        }
        for(k=j;k>=2;k--){
            printf("%c ", num+k-1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
}
```

But, it outputs this:

```
A B C D E F G G F E D C B A                                                                                       
  A B C D E F F E D C B A                                                                                          
   A B C D E E D C B A                                                                                             
    A B C D D C B A                                                                                                
     A B C C B A                                                                                                   
      A B B A  
       A A
```

So, I'm generating the alphabets the right way but just having some trouble with the spaces. So, please could you identify the changes I need to make in order to achieve the desired output or maybe provide an alternative solution (has to use nested for loops), would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: `printf("%*c", i * 2, ' ');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
printf("%*c", i, ' ');
```

I added

```
if(i>=2) printf("%*c", i-1, ' ');
```

And it worked